# Spring child-parent contexts with multiple application.properties files using spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I used spring boot to use external application.properties.
My application use a parent context and children contexts which have the same xml file (all children have the same behaviour) but each child  has its own configuration for example:

the file app_child1.properties:

> directory.name=directoryChild1

and the file app_child2.properties:

> directory.name=directoryChild2

and the main application.properties contains the common configuration and the list of children application.properties.

Is it possible to do it using spring boot ? 
and how to assign each app_childx.properties to the appropriate context?

my code is as the following:

```
 ConfigurableApplicationContext childCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                    new String[] { "/META-INF/spring/integration/dynamic-ftp-inbound-adapter-context.xml" },
                    parent);

childCtx.setEnvironment(env);
```

How to set Environment for each context from a file application.properties.
And is it possible to create context dynamicaly with spring boot with the above method ?